# Angular Material 2 - changing md-select placeholder color

Tags: angular, angular-material

Couldn't find any proper way to overwrite the defaults.

Simply this:

```
<md-select class="selector"
      color="primary"
      placeholder="Date Format" --> change this color
      [(ngModel)]="dateType" name="dateType">
        <md-option value="1">Option 1</md-option>
        <md-option value="2">Option 2</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Trying to overwrite any of the placeholder classes didn't do it:

```
md-select, .mat-select-placeholder, .mat-select-trigger {
  color:white !important;
}
```

Anyone got a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

The quick way to override CSS is to add your CSS block in styles.css (or .scss or .sass) file in `./src`.

```
md-select, .mat-select-placeholder, .mat-select-trigger {
  color:white !important;
}
```

**Summary:** You cannot apply CSS on any "Angular Material generated HTML elements" in `your.component.css` file because Angular adds `[_ngcontent-cXX]` attribute selectors to all rules defined in it on compilation to keep your CSS rules in scope of only your component.

**Edit:** As pointed out by @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas (thanks!), we can use `/deep/` to apply styles across components. However, Angular is [deprecating](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) `deep`. So, we do not seem to have a long-term-supported way of doing this.

Comment: You can, easily, in SCSS. Just use `/deep/`. Eg. `/deep/ md-select {... }`

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas true. I found out only later; and forgot that I had posted this. But, I also found recently that `/deep/` is being deprecated. Hope I did not misunderstand their documentation. https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Comment: Hm. It is interesting that they do not mention what to use in place of the deprecated ones -- they suggest using `::ng-deep` which is also on the deprecation list.

Comment: True. Anyway, I updated my answer as per our conversation. Thanks.

Comment: I tried adding the .mat-select-trigger{ font-size:14px !important} in src/styles.scss, and the ng rebulds automatically, but it still stayed 16px.

Comment: Overriding fonts is using this hack technique is the same. You just need to make sure you set the `font-size` on the right class name. I think in your case, you might want to do it on one of the `md-option` classes.

**Recommended technique:** Theme your [Angular Material typography](https://material.angular.io/guide/typography#customization). It is much clearer, cooler and simple (once you get the hang of it, you'll love it).

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the below  style classes,

```
.mat-select:focus:not(.mat-select-disabled).mat-primary .mat-select-arrow,
.mat-select:focus:not(.mat-select-disabled).mat-primary .mat-select-trigger {
  color: red;
}

.mat-select-arrow,
.mat-select-disabled .mat-select-value,
.mat-select-trigger {
  color:orange;

}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/rESTsfn31yLJzs7sdMcG?p=preview)

Comment: Your live demo is broken.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas all material design plunkers are broken. :( Raised a [github issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/6754)

Comment: Probably related to the push to the 2.0.0-beta10, which moved around the cdk references. :(

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas yes.. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
.mat-form-field-label,.mat-select-arrow
{
    color: white !important;
}
```

Placeholder text color change and Arrow